# How to simplify this with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I have the following javascript function  :

```
function render(id) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            Flights.get(id).then(function(flightDto){

              Arrivals.getDemoProfile(flightDto.id).then(function(arrivalDto) {

                self.arivalId = arrivalDto.id;
                deferred.resolve(self);

              });

            });

            return deferred.promise;

}
```

Is there any way I can simplify better using promise so that the promise only resolves after the arrivals call is made? I am using angular and the built in $q library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function render(id) {
    return Flights.get(id).then(function(flightDto) {
        return Arrivals.getDemoProfile(flightDto.id).then(function(arrivalDto) {
            self.arivalId = arrivalDto.id;
            return self;
        });
    });
}
```

Anything you `return` inside a `then` will be treated as the resolve of that promise.
Unless you return a promise, in which case that will be waited for, and the result will be treated as the resolve of that promise.

This means you can nest the then as deeply as you need and just keep returning from the nested functions.

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about promises is that they can be *chained* instead of being nested. This makes the code a lot clearer and easier to reason (about which comes first for example). Following is the code from Buh Buh's answer, improved to chain the second promise instead of nesting:

```
function render(id) {
    return Flights.get(id)
        .then(function(flightDto) {
            return Arrivals.getDemoProfile(flightDto.id);
        })
        .then(function(arrivalDto) {
            self.arivalId = arrivalDto.id;
            return self; // I AM NOT SURE ABOUT THE USEFULNESS OF THIS LINE...
        })
    ;
}
```

Comment: Yea, this probably better.  For some reason I'm more comfortable nesting, but I think most people would recommend chaining.